# How to know which item is clicked in richfaces PickList

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I am using richfaces 4.1.0M2 with JSF2.0 and I have a PickList and what I want is that when someone selects (mouse click) an item in the left list, some component in the form is updated based on what is clicked. I have managed to trigger an event in the bean whan some one clicks on an item. The code to achieve the trigger is

```
<rich:pickList showButtonsLabel="false" value="#{groupBean.pickListResult}"
                                    listHeight="100"  converter="#{groupBean.converter}">
                                    <a4j:ajax event="click" render="userlist" limitRender="true" listener="#{groupBean.updateGroupMembers}"/> 
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{groupBean.leftPickList}" />
                       </rich:pickList>
```

But I am not able to get the value of SelectItem which was clicked. Any idea how I can do that. I read in the documentation that each item has three states associated with it in the PickList i.e common, selected, active. So is there a way to get these states in the bean. Any idea.

Answer (score 0):

The selected value will be available in groupBean.pickListResult (on the server)

Comment: Actually I want those element which are highlighted with a mouse click before they are moved to the pickListResult.

Comment: If you want to select multiple values, then don't use a4j:ajax with click event as this will only allow you to select one value. Without Ajax, select any number of items and then click a submit button.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you Should use `onchange` Event in `<a:support>`

```
ex: <a4j:ajax event="onchange" render="userlist" limitRender="true" />
```